# Simplifying Boolean Expression x'yz + xy'z + xyz' + xyz

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

Hi I'v solved this halfway, please help me for the rest.
so far I've got..

```
    x'yz + xy'z + xyz' + xyz
    z(x'y + xy') + xy(z'+z)
    z(x'y + xy') + xy
```

i don't understand how to solve the ***z(x'y + xy')*** part of this expression.. please somebody help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x'y + xy'` is XOR.  So you can simplify to `z(x+y) + xy` because `z(x'y + xy') + xy` is `z` when `x != y` and `xy` when `x == y`.

The `(x+y)` after `z` is necessary to disallow influence of `z` when `x == y == 0`.